# Do infinite summation rules still hold when lower bound of summation is some constant N?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Given (for example) the following infinite series:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}
\end{equation}
Does this still hold when e.g. the lower bound is changed to some positive number $K$ that is NOT $\infty$. So if for example $K = 6$, the summation is then the following
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=6}^{\infty}x^n
\end{equation}
Does it still hold that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=6}^{\infty}x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}
\end{equation}

Comment: No, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n  $ and $\sum_{n=6}^{\infty}x^n  $ have a difference (namely, $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5$)

Comment: Write the first few terms of both series and compare.

Comment: $\sum_{n=6}^\infty x^n = \left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right] - \left[\sum_{n=0}^5 x^n\right]$.  **Alternative approach:** Let $m = n-6$.  Then $\sum_{n=6}^\infty x^n = \sum_{m=0}^\infty x^{m+6} = x^6 \times \sum_{m=0}^\infty x^m.$

Comment: My question is then: why would those terms matter if the summation goes to infinity anyways?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Why would you think that it would? You're discarding the first five terms of the sum.

This is a geometric series. The infinite sum only converges for $|x| < 1$, so let's assume that holds.

The finite geometric sum from the first to the $n$-th term is $S_n = \frac{a(1-x^n)}{1-x}$. There is no special condition on $x$ for convergence of a finite sum, but obviously it works fine for $|x| < 1$ as well.

So what you want here is $S_{\infty} - S_5 = \frac a{1-x} - \frac{a(1-x^5) }{1-x}$.

You can simplify the algebra yourself.

Edit:

It is instructive (and often safest) to derive the elementary formulas ourselves rather than blindly applying what we memorised or found.

Here: $S_n = a + ax + ax^2 + \cdots + ax^{n-1}$

And a little thought would tell you that this is a sum to $n$ terms since you're starting from $ax^0$ and ending with $ax^{n-1}$. From $0$ to $n-1$, there are $n$ terms and this is the usual convention for $S_n$.

Now multiply throughout by $x$:

$xS_n = ax + ax^2 + ax^3 + \cdots + ax^n$

Subtract the first identity from the second, term by term. Every term cancels except two:

$xS_n - S_n = -a + ax^n$

$(x-1)S_n = a(x^n - 1)$

$\therefore S_n = \frac {a(x^n - 1)} {x-1} $

And by multiplying by $-1$ on top and bottom you get the completely equivalent identity:

$S_n = \frac {a(1- x^n)} {1-x} $

If you now impose the condition that $|x| < 1$ and you take a limit, you can easily show that:

$S_{\infty} = \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = \frac {a} {1-x} $

because at the limit, the $x^n$ term vanishes.

Comment: Thanks this clarified my confusion

Comment: I forgot to ask, why is it $S_5 = \frac{a(1-x^5)}{1-x}$ instead of $S_5 = \frac{a(1-x^6)}{1-x}$? reference: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html

Comment: @alexSDE My answer was correct from the start. The formula you quoted is summing $n+1$ terms not $n$. I don't like that reference in general as it seems to deviate from convention quite frequently.

Comment: @alexSDE I have added the full derivation here for clarity. I actually like doing this myself on a piece of paper when in doubt as my memory is crap.

Comment: Ok I see now, I appreciate the effort!

Answer (score 1):

No, and in fact this should be obvious on inspection from a numerical perspective.

For instance, let's calculate

$$\sum_{k=6}^N x^k$$

using Microsoft Excel, for various $N$ and $x=1/2$:

[image]

Clearly, as $N \to\infty$, we're not going to the usual result.

In fact,

$$\sum_{k=6}^\infty x^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k - \sum_{k=0}^5 x^k$$